# JavaFX hover only when not selected CSS

Tags: javafx-2

I have CSS for hover and selected etc:

```
.my-class-name:hover
{
    .fx-background-color: red;
}
.my-class-name:selected
{
    .fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

In this example the background of selected element is blue.
Is there way when the mouse hover the selected element it will stay with background blue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same problem, try this one :

```
.my-class-name:hover
{
    .fx-background-color: red;
}
.my-class-name:selected
{
    .fx-background-color: blue;
}
.my-class-name:selected:hover
{
    .fx-background-color: blue;
}
```